# Keychain : SecItemAdd: missing entitlement (release build)

Tags: ios, keychain

my applications saves Username/Password in keychain using PDKeychainBindings.

When I lauch my app from xCode (debug build) it works, but when I compile a release build, resign it (using erica sadun's signit shell script) and install it in my device, saving into keychain always failed.

I get this keychain errors:

```
Jul 31 11:44:50 Thierrys-iPhone securityd[1903] <Error>: myAPP[1898] SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement
Jul 31 11:44:50 Thierrys-iPhone securityd[1903] <Error>: myAPP[1898] SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement
Jul 31 11:44:50 Thierrys-iPhone securityd[1903] <Error>: myAPP[1898] SecItemAdd: missing entitlement
Jul 31 11:44:50 Thierrys-iPhone securityd[1903] <Error>: myAPP[1898] SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement
Jul 31 11:44:50 Thierrys-iPhone securityd[1903] <Error>: myAPP[1898] SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement
```

Do you have an idea what is the problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem as well. I was using the [floatsign.sh](https://gist.github.com/mediabounds/1367348) script - and have now modified it to correctly handle resizing for keychains.
To do so, the entitlements file has to be update to reflect the new provisioning file. Check out the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Weptun/5406993)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that resigning with erica's script causes the problem. 
Signing with xCode and distribute the build does not cause this problem.